# Should I mine bitcoins or litecoins?

Tags: litecoin, mining-profitability, gpu, cpu

I don't pay for my own power, but I have two problems mining. I am CPU mining at 250 mhash/s because my AMD Radeon HD 7800 series graphics card will only produce 4.0 mhash/s (the other problem I'm having that I don't understand) but my main question is- what is more profitable to me? litecoin mining or bitcoin mining?

Answer (score 11):

Litecoin mining is currently more profitable for likely all GPUs.

From the [bitcoin](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison#CPUs.2FAPUs) and [litecoin](https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison) hardware wikis, you'd get 300-400MH/s for bitcoin mining and 340-470kH/s for litecoin mining if you set it up properly (and there is something VERY fishy about you getting 250MH/s with your CPU, I'd guess it is using your GPU though you don't know it...).

For bitcoin, the [current difficulty](http://bitcoin.sipa.be/) is about 6,500TH/s.  Thus, you'd own about 300/6,500,000,000 of the network.  At 25 bitcoins per block, 6*24 blocks per day, and $800 per bitcoin, you'd make about $0.13/day.  There is specifically-designed hardware for mining Bitcoins, which is way more powerful than GPUs, so unless you can buy a dedicated mining ASIC, your energy bill would overcome your revenue.

For litecoin, the [current difficulty](http://bitcoinwisdom.com/litecoin/difficulty) is about 90GH/s.  Thus, you'd own about 340/90,000,000 of the network.  At 4*6*24 blocks per day, 50 litecoins per block, and $25 per litecoin, you'd make about $2.72/day.  It uses a different algorithm (called Scrypt) than Bitcoin. FPGAs and ASICs can't be optimized for this algorithm as much as they can be optimized for Bitcoins' algorithm, so Litecoins are mined exclusively with GPUs. This means that you can still be comptetitive, and you should mine those.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet with a GPU is to mine scrypt coins.  If you want the resulting payout to be in bitcoin, try using mining on a multi-pool like [middlecoin.com](http://middlecoin.com). That pool automatically chooses the most profitable scrypt-based coin to mine and pays out daily in bitcoin.
I have 4 7950s pointing at middlecoin and make between .05 to .1 bitcoin per day.

Comment: Could you describe your hardware configuration please ? How many GPU cards, computers and model ?

Comment: I cite: "I have 4 7950s"

Answer (score 1):

Dogecoin is the most profitable scrypt coin as of today.

With growth from 0.05 BTC for 1 million to 0.35 BTC and difficulty rise from 4 to 101.67 in a week. Dec 9 - Dec 15, 2013

Comment: Citation needed.

Comment: It's still the most profitable as of 21/Dec according to dustcoin.com , and one of the most profitables according to coinwarz.com . Seems to have been among the most profitable for most of the month but of course, nobody knows how much time it will keep that place.

Comment: I find the dog, "comic sans" font and the language used in the GUI to be über-cute. I understand some people seem to hate with passion the same 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a choice. You will not do much mining bitcoins with MH/s. You need at least a few GH/s. Not sure about litecoin. If you want to mine bitcoins you have to look for specific hardware ([butterfly labs](http://www.butterflylabs.com/) [kncminer](https://www.kncminer.com/)) or cloudmining like [cexio](https://cex.io/r/1/giagola/0/)